# What is the size of a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

In c++, If I defined a string `string x ="call"`;
, what's the size of x?
Is it 4 bytes? or Should I count the null byte so that the size is 5?

Comment: Have you tried `x.size()` ? ;-)

Comment: On most implementations, `sizeof(string)` is either 12 or 24 bytes.

Comment: well, that depends on what you mean by "size", and also whose size, `x` or "call".

Comment: Do you mean `sizeof(x)` or `x.size()`?

Comment: @user3528438 I mean how many bytes is there in the string "call"?
I think x is a pointer, isn't it?

Comment: no, x is not a pointer, is an object that contains a pointer to the memory containing the string bytes (possibly with a final null). [x.size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) (or x.length() ) will return the length of your string

Comment: Then the answer is 5 since "call" is a c-style string with 4 chars and 1 null terminator so 5 bytes in total (could be known by `sizeof("call")`). However it is used to initialize an `std::string` object called x (no, not x is not a pointer). The size of x object can be known by `sizeof(x)` which is implementation defined. The length of the string x contains can be known by `x.size()` or `x.length()` which should be both 4.

Answer (score 3):

A string has a function size() that you can call to get the length of it:

```
int size = x.size();
```

Comment: It doesn't count the null!
Is that OK?

Comment: Why do you care about the (possible) null ?

Comment: @IbrahimFathy `std::string`s do not have to be nul-terminated.

Comment: @Quentin: Actually, from an implementation standpoint, they do. ;) (`&x[x.size()]` is guaranteed to be `0`)

Comment: @IbrahimFathy What null? The null that was at the end of the string you used to initialize it? Why should it count that? It's not part of `x`, is it?

Comment: [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) distinguishes between C++98 and C++11. A terminating null-character is guaranteed for C++11 but not for C++98.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I was about to sneak around the weird wording for `operator[]`, but apparently I (and three people who upvoted my comment) am still in C++98 on this point: `data()` is nul-terminated since C++11, so this isn't even an implementation detail.

Comment: @Quentin: Arguably, the string itself and the result of `data()` are not logically _quite_ the same thing. But you could probably call it either way.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition **21.4.7.1**, `std::basic_string::data()`: "*Returns*: A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`." Well, that doesn't imply anything indeed :)

Comment: @Shadow `c_str()` is guaranteed to be null terminated even in C++98. The only practical way to meet that requirement is to ensure that the internal data buffer is also null terminated. I'm sure that's why the change to `data()` was added to C++11, because everybody already met the requirement.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, I know what `data()` does; I was the first to point out that `&x[x.size()]` must be `0`. The question is whether you consider this part of the "implementation" (poor choice of words perhaps; try "mechanism" instead) or logically part of the string. Personally, as long as `std::string::size()` doesn't include it, I prefer to say that "the size of the string" doesn't include it either.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I did know of the special wording for `x[x.size()]`, but not that `data()` is defined in terms of `operator[]`. Anyway, I agree with you on the conceptual part.

Comment: @Quentin: They go hand in hand due to various guarantees linking it all together

Answer (score 0):

As you can check from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/), by calling string.size() you obtain a size without the null terminator. The example in that page is:

```
// string::size
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("Test string");
  std::cout << "The size of str is " << str.size() << " bytes.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

> The size of str is 11 bytes

"Test string" is exactly 11 bytes, so no null terminator.